# Mouse event to hide and show button makes button non responding

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void panelControl1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      button2.Show();
}

private void panelControl1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      button2.Hide();
}
```

[image]

When I enter the panel, button shows up but clicking on button doesn't work. Above are the image and code.

Comment: Show button click `event`.

Comment: Do you have a button2_Click event handler? What should this do?

Comment: How you are saying that the button click not working?

Comment: I have button click event and it is not triggered. At the same time the animation that we see while clicking button is also not showing.

Comment: @SrikanthPVasist. Yes as user tries to click on `button` inside panel. Both `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events of the panel keeps on firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is workaround for this issue. You can create your own `CustomPanel` class. 
After adding this class you can replace your `Panel` in the **Designer.cs** with `CustomPanel`.

```
namespace System.Windows.Forms
{
    public class CustomPanel : Panel
    {
        protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.ClientRectangle.Contains(this.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)))
                return;
            else
            {
                base.OnMouseLeave(e);
            }
        }
   }
}
```

`CustomPanel` class restricts invalid firing of `MouseLeave` event whenever user hover any child control of panel.

Answer (score 0):

MouseEnter occurs when the mouse enters the "visible" part of the control and MouseLeave  occurs when the mouse leaves the "visible" part of the control. over the button isn't the visible part of panelControl.